# Android Cursor Index Out of Bounds

Tags: android, null, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

In my app I have many sql queries which are streaming row data from the tables to the files.  In these quesries I have my Sql Cursors which basically order my columns by the value of another and then pulls the values of the first row.  Problem is that once that cursor reaches the end of my table, then the app crashes becasue of zero values.

```
    public static String evalLightTable(String filenamePrefix){


    String[] lightcolumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LUXVALUE, KEY_TRANSMITTED};
    Cursor elightcursor = myDatabase.query(LIGHT_TABLE, lightcolumns, KEY_TID + "=" + filenamePrefix + " AND " + KEY_TRANSMITTED + "=" + nottransmitted, null, null, null, null);       
    String notTransmitted = "";

    int iRowId = elightcursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);

    if (elightcursor != null) {
        elightcursor.moveToFirst();
        String lightRowId = elightcursor.getString(0);
        return lightRowId;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The above is the sample query that I am running.  Below is the logCat which applies:

```
07-04 13:21:14.697: E/AndroidRuntime(19537): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

07-04 13:21:14.697: E/AndroidRuntime(19537):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
```

In my query I am asking it to retrieve data as long as the cursor finds something.  It should be that if it does not, it should definitely not crash.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor does not contain any result rows. You should check that the `moveTo..()` succeeded before accessing data.

Additionally, `query()` in `SQLiteDatabase` never returns null so the null check is redundant.

Therefore, replace

```
if (elightcursor != null) {
    elightcursor.moveToFirst();
```

with

```
if (elightcursor.moveToFirst()) {
```

Comment: I like this answer much better.  It made perfect sense.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you didn't check the result count. As well as remove variable iRowId.

```
    public static String evalLightTable(String filenamePrefix){


String[] lightcolumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TID, KEY_NAME, KEY_LUXVALUE, KEY_TRANSMITTED};
Cursor elightcursor = myDatabase.query(LIGHT_TABLE, lightcolumns, KEY_TID + "=" + filenamePrefix + " AND " + KEY_TRANSMITTED + "=" + nottransmitted, null, null, null, null);       
String notTransmitted = "";


if (elightcursor != null && elightcursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    elightcursor.moveToFirst();
    String lightRowId = elightcursor.getString(0);
    return lightRowId;
}
return null;
```

}